# Determine which clock has arrived first

Tags: fpga, rtl

There are two clocks of the same frequency, but one has a phase shift. So we have two clocks, one leading and one lagging. How can we determine which clock has arrived first?

One way would be to use another faster clock in the design to sample these two clocks and make a decision.

Is there any simpler way to achieve this in RTL?

Comment: Sample the clocks, hmm, and what if the time difference is less than the sample rate ? Also, sounds to me like a cumbersome solution. What do you need to detect the timing difference ? The edges ! What can detect an edge ? A flip-flip. So use two flip-flops (one for each clock) and detect which one sets first. Also: Phase-locked-loops use this sort of circuit to lock the local clock to an external reference clock. In PLLs this circuit is called **phase detector** or **phase frequency detector**.

Comment: Are your clocks digital or sinewave-ish? Do they have any even-order harmonic components (do they have 50/50 duty cycle)?

Comment: "So we have two clocks, one leading and one lagging." No you don't. If you take either clock as reference, the other will be lagging that reference. Of course, the second may be lagging by nearly a full clock period, but that's just a large lag. You know, like 359+ degrees of phase shift. So you need to set forth your criteria for determining which should be the reference.

Answer (score 3):

Latch clock A on the rising edge of clock B. If the result is high then A arrived first.

Of course this is assuming you have zero setup and hold times on the data inputs of your latches or that you know the phase shift is always going to be of a certain magnitude. In the real world with small phase shifts it gets a lot harder to be sure.

Comment: This is assuming that B has the phase shift. If you don't know which clock will have the phase shift then ?

Comment: @user22348 if you're assuming that only one clock has phase shift, it means you don't understand phase shift.

Comment: @user22348 if the result is low the B arrived first. It does matter which clock has the phase shift. If you shift A by a positive amount that is identical to shifting B by a negative amount.

Answer (score 0):

A phase detector or phase comparator is an essential element of the phase locked loop PLL: [link](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC14046B-D.PDF). The phase comparator output signal is then filtered with low pass filter and then it drives a voltage controlled oscillator (VCO). You may use only the first part of the PLL IC