# Determining which pulse came first on an FPGA

Tags: fpga, clock, pulse

I try to determine which of two asynchronous pulses came first (after a synchronous reset) using an FPGA. The pulses are asynchronous because they are generated from ring oscillators (running on the FPGA and not synchronized with the system clock).

I want to use as few resources as possible. Should I use [a latch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/327024/80406) or some flip-flops like below?

[image: schematic] [source](https://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/gated-counter-determines-which-two-pulses-came-first)

I am looking for a solution where the output stay stable even if subsequent pulses are generated.

Comment: Do you have a clock that runs at least at twice the frequency of the fastest of both ring oscillators?

Comment: Not at all. The ring oscillators oscillates at ~5-10x the speed of the system clock.

Comment: What you have drawn above will not work. The best I can think off is the old fashioned two-nand-gates-with-feedback Flip-Flop.

Comment: Define "first" -- first after what event?

Comment: After a synchronous reset.

Comment: You also need to worry about metastability. You have two high-speed asynchronous signals coming into a synchronous system. At some point, perhaps after your initial which-one-is-first circuit, you need to synchronize the asynchronous inputs with the synchronous system.

Comment: How far apart can your two pulses be? Are we talking picoseconds here? What kind of resolution are you after?

Comment: What is the FPGA clock speed and the ring oscillator clock speed? You may need to increase the FPGA clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the transition of clocks to lock other out from changing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEeB5F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Either locks out the other, unless both occur at the same time, where both latch with L_R_SELECT having precedence.

Reset clears flip-flops to start sequence.

Comment: Why are the bars of the "Q bar"/"Q not" (_Q_ near _RESET_) from the flip-flops not visible in the schematic?

Comment: If you edit the image they are there.  Just resolution of the custom part.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick draft, I'm not sure if my idea would work or not:

[image]

**explanation:** at first, you reset the two flips flops: hence **Q1 = Q2 = 0**.

Pulse 1 is applied to clk1 and pulse 2 is applied to clk2.

We have **D1 = 1 xor Q2 = 1 xor 0 = 1**, same for **D2 = 1**.
When the first pulse occurs, let's say pulse 1, **Q1** will be set to D1 = 1 and hence the LED 1 will turn on.

Then the second pulse will occur, but now at **D2** we will have **1 xor 1 = 0** so **Q2** will remain at **0** and LED 2 will remain turned off.

So the only LED that will be ON indicates which pulse occurred first.

And this state will remain stable, even if subsequent pulses occur.

But you have to be sure that the propagation delays of your gates are lower than the period of your oscillators.

Comment: Why has it been downvoted?

Comment: You could also hook each D to the other not-Q.  That way the first clk would reset not-Q, and subsequent clocks would have no effect until the next reset.  The XOR gates above are essentially inverters.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis yes you are right, I haven't noticed. We could spare two xor gates.

Comment: I'm the downvoter, this won't work, the clocks are completely independent, so there is no lower bound on the required propagation delay that would ensure no race conditions/metastability will occur. So it's a bad answer.

Comment: @DonFusili OK I understand, thank you.

Comment: @DonFusili If the two pulses arrive so close to each other so that they provoke metastability, we can also argue that the output is undecidable anyway. If both output signals (leds) do not trigger anything but instead are read asynchronously, then this might be good enough if we accept that the output could be random/garbage if pulses are too close. Is there any issue with my reasoning?

Comment: @DurandA None except you really should put your boundary conditions in the question. If it comes down to "make something that works except when it doesn't", we shouldn't have to guess that intention.

Comment: @DonFusili I agree, but I expected a simple _universal_ solution to exist for this problem. Why did you remove your answer?

Comment: Can you edit your answer with @Cristobol Polychronopolis suggestion and to clearly state the possible metastability issue? I will accept your answer.